# Can you add a button instead of an "alt" text?

Tags: javascript, html, lightcase.js

I am trying to have a button under the image when it opens. I am trying to do it with the  attribute but the button shows outside of the "image box" I am going to put some images to refer what I am talking about.

[image]

Now the `alt` attribute is the text that displays currently.

Where it says beach chairs I would like to show the buy later button. The js plugin that I am using is called    lightcase.js

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fashion photography showcase" data-rel="lightcase">
    <a href="img/sale.png"  data-rel="lightcase"class="portfolio_item">
        <img src="img/womenn.png" alt="this t-shirt is awesome"class="img-responsive">
        <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
            <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                <div class="item_info">
                    <span>Women's Style </span> <em>Fashion</em>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to show a button, when the image is not loaded into DOM correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to put a image ontop of an image, and place a button below the inner image

> "Where it says beach chairs i would like to show the buy later button."

then try this below code.

That should produce the same output as in the referenced site ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/52bgM.jpg) in your question.

```css
.background-img {
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/200x200/fedabc");
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 300px;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image {}
```

```html
<div class="background-img">
  <div class="inner_img">

    <div class="image"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200"></img>
    </div>
    <button> button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript watch for the image to load. If the alt test is going to be displayed it will throw an error during the load phase of the image. At that point replace with a button.

To be more direct, no you cannot simply inject a button to the alt text.

Essentially what the following javascript does is it gets the image and sets an onload event listener, if there is an error replace the img with a button.

```js
var img = $('#test');

img.on('load', function(e){
    alert('Success!');
}).on('error', function(e) {
    $('#test').replaceWith('<button>click me</button>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fashion photography showcase" data-rel="lightcase">
    <a href="img/sale.png"  data-rel="lightcase"class="portfolio_item">
    <img id="test" src="img/womenn.png" alt="alt text"class="img-responsive">
    <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
        <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
            <div class="item_info"> <span>Women's Style </span> <em>Fashion</em>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </a>
</div>
```